# The two javascript filters only run separately, not together

Tags: javascript, function, filter

Revised: I have been making a filter for a search bar that will not read hyphens and read all lowercase letters as upper case. Both of these work but only for whichever condition applies first and then it disregards the other condition entirely. If I type in a hyphen first I wont get an error but if I type a lower case letter in addition to the hyphen I get an error and vice versa. I've

The first function is:

```js
function filterTable(event) {
  var Case = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
  var Hyphen = event.target.value.replace(/[-]/g, "");
  var rows = document.querySelector("#Catalogue").rows;

  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var firstCol = rows[i].cells[0].textContent.toUpperCase().replace(/[-]/g, '');
    var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase().replace(/[-]/g, '');
    if (firstCol.indexOf(Case) > -1 || thirdCol.indexOf(Case) > -1 || firstCol.indexOf(Hyphen) > -1 || thirdCol.indexOf(Hyphen) > -1) {
      rows[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no difference between 2 functions

Comment: They are the same, but if they're both written like that then the one that was applied most recently will set the rows display property directly. If you need to filter on multiple fields at the same time then rather get the values of the filters directly (instead of from the event) and add both values in your if condition.

Comment: JavaScript's Boolean operators feature "short-circuiting", meaning, in the case of ORs, it will only run the first condition, if that condition is truthy.

Comment: Is there another way to filter all of the conditions without short-circuiting it? I've tried using the && function but I've had no luck. Thank you for your help!